# PHP email sending issue

Tags: php, email

My contact form is sending emails out but for someone reason, I am not receiving emails in my gmail account. I am receiving emails on other email providers like Yahoo. So I think that there is a problem with my headers.

```
$headers = 'From: ' .$email . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: ' .$email . "\r\n" .
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: FYI - control characters like `\n` are only interpreted in double-quoted strings. I'd also be checking your spam folder

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a period instead of a semi-colon

```
'Reply-To: ' .$email . "\r\n" .
                              ^
```

Change it to:

```
$headers = 'From: ' .$email . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: ' .$email . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

which is breaking your headers

Comment: works fine.. receiving emails on my gmail account but hotmail is still blocking the email... any way to have hotmail not block it?

Comment: There's hardly anything you can do about Hotmail unfortunately. You may get better luck using PHPmailer, but that's never a guarantee. I too use similar headers, and 95% of the time, Hotmail sends it to Spam. Microsoft is just strange that way. @user3291093

Comment: If you feel this matter has been solved, let's close the question then. @user3291093

Comment: @user3291093 First you accepted my answer, then you changed your mind.

Comment: Sorry about that, I was trying to see if I can delete the question... I thought the question I asked was not a good question

Comment: @user3291093 Why would you want to delete it? It's been up for a few months now.

Comment: Someone from chat downvoted it randomly by going on to my profile which isnt fair